# Firebase runTransaction() goes on an infinite loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently trying to implement a way to count how many times a post of my database is display on my users' screen. To manage possible simultaneous modifications, I decided to use the `runTransition()` method. I am calling this method in the method I use to populate my viewHolder.

Yet, the `runTransition()` method goes on an infinite loop and keeps on incrementing my `nb_views` counter - even if the app is running on only one phone with a stationary newsfeed.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
private void setupPost(final PostViewHolder postViewHolder, final Post post, final int position, final String inPostKey) {

    /.../

    DatabaseReference ref = (FirebaseUtil.getPostsRef()).child(postKey).child("nb_views");
    ref.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
        @Override
        public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
            if (mutableData.getValue() != null) {
                long nb = (long) mutableData.getValue();
                mutableData.setValue(nb + 1);
            }
            else {
                mutableData.setValue(1);
            }

            return Transaction.success(mutableData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "postTransaction:onComplete:" + databaseError);
        }
    });

    /.../
```

The `onComplete()` method is called everytime without any errors. The most surprising thing might be that the entire `setupPost()` method is called indefinitely. When I remove the `runTransaction()` method, everything is normal and the `setupPost()` method is called only once for each post...

Any ideas why I get an infinite loop?

Comment: I bet(well, with use of common sense) that setupPost is called from onDataChange which is as its name says called when data had changed... Which is obviously done with this transaction...

Comment: Hmm, yes, it was actually the case... I feel quite dumb for that. I guess I'm just going to count the views outside of the post object itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think i am answering too late,but might be helpful for someone.

Your setupPost() method is called repeatedly when your firebase runTransaction() is executing because somewhere in this activity(or fragment), or previous activity (or fragment) calling this activity their is a value listener on the same firebase child, which is calling the setupPost() method everytime their is a change in value in the database.

Change all the value listener to single value listener and your problem will be solved.